# Raspbarry pi cm3+ lite sd-speed

Tags: sd-card, compute-module-3, compute-module-development-kit

I managed to get the board booting from sd-card, but I noticed when I use the regular pi 3+ my boot times are much faster, in fact 1,5 times faster. I have tinkered with the config.txt file, trying to increase the SD-Card speed of the cm3+ lite, my usual settings for pi3 are

> dtoverlay=sdhost,overclock_50=100

and I tried those settings on my cm3+ lite, but without results.I tryed

> dtoverlay=sdio,overclock=100,poll_once=0

that should actually work for the cm io board, but also without results.

Does anyone have an idea, how to increase the sd-card speed on cm3+, I have tryed multiple settings on dtoverlay=sdio, but none of them seemed to yield any result.

PS:

> dtoverlay=sdhost,overclock_50=100

works perfectly with my indastrialgrade sd-cards and we use them since 3 years in thousends of devices without any failure yet.

raspberry-pi iot raspbian sd-card